# how to display a custom dialog above particular layout in android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a layout at the bottom. Trying to pop up a dialog above this layout. Refer the screenshot [image] Can someone help me?

This is my activity

```
    package com.example.dynamicviews;

    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutSend;
    TextView txt_attach;
    EditText edit_reply;
    TextView txt_send;
    TextView txt_showattach;
    ViewPager pager;
    Dialog attachmentDialog;
    ImageView img_attachment;
    ImageView img_emailtemplate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);


        relativeLayoutSend=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutSend);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_attach=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params_attach.leftMargin=20;
        txt_attach=new TextView(this);
        txt_attach.setId(R.id.relativeLayoutSend+1);
        txt_attach.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        txt_attach.setLayoutParams(params_attach);
        params_attach.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        params_attach.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        relativeLayoutSend.addView(txt_attach);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_reply=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        edit_reply=new EditText(this);
        edit_reply.setEms(13);
        edit_reply.setLayoutParams(params_reply);
        params_reply.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        relativeLayoutSend.addView(edit_reply);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_send=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params_send.rightMargin=20;
        txt_send=new TextView(this);
        txt_send.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        txt_send.setLayoutParams(params_send);
        params_send.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params_send.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        relativeLayoutSend.addView(txt_send);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_showattach=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params_showattach.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params_attach.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        txt_showattach=new TextView(this);
        params_showattach.leftMargin=40;
        txt_showattach.setLayoutParams(params_showattach);
        relativeLayoutSend.addView(txt_showattach);


        txt_attach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attachmentDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.PauseDialog);
                attachmentDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_attachment);
                attachmentDialog.setCancelable(true);
                img_attachment = (ImageView) attachmentDialog.findViewById(R.id.img_attachment);
                img_emailtemplate = (ImageView) attachmentDialog.findViewById(R.id.img_template);

                attachmentDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT;

                WindowManager.LayoutParams params=attachmentDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.y=300;
                attachmentDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                attachmentDialog.show();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my xml

custom_attachment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup_element"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#0054ae"
android:layout_marginLeft="16sp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_attachment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_template"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_attachment"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.dynamicviews.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#0054ae">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of setting `params.y = 300` in which alignment varies for different devices i need to set params.above `relativeLayoutSend`. How can i do that?

Comment: You can always use the PopupWindow view to display such things. Here's an article  https://iamnaran.medium.com/creating-an-android-popup-menu-view-10955fea7de8 that may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Builder class will help you in doing that.

Example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(urlayout);
builder.setTitle("urtitle");
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
alertDialog.show();
```

As you are getting the window and then setting layout width and height, it shouldn't affect.

To show the dialog at the bottom of the screen.

Example:

```
Dialog dialogue = <your custom dialog>;

Window window = dialogue.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutparam = window.getAttributes();

layoutparam .gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
layoutparam .flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(layoutparam );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is if we give setLayout(600, 400) it will be displayed in a y postion in nexus 6 and another y position in some other devices.. Is there any way to position the dialog above the relative layout at the bottom by margin bottom? Then only the dialog will occur in the same position in all devices